# Can I access a pointer as a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Lets' say I have a pointer to int:

```
int *p = somefunc();
```

I know it points to 25 ints, logically arranged in a 5x5 grid. I can access an element with this:

```
p[y*5+x]
```

or this:

```
*(p+y*5+x)
```

Is there a way access it as a 2D array?

```
a[y][x]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

```
int (*a)[5] = (int (*)[5])p;
```

Comment: Is it not possible without explicit casting?

Comment: @TorKlingberg As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a simple function to do it :

```
int at(int * p, int x, int y)
{
    return p[y*5+x]
}
```

You can add another parameter for less specific width of table (i.e. other that 5), but that's how I usually do it.